# LDAP Create two users with same username in different OUs

Tags: c#, ldap

In my AD, I can't login after i have created two users with same user name - Alex in different OU. They have different sAMAccountName.

Error:

> Call method - auehtnticateUser.
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007052E):
>   The user name or password is incorrect.
>
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean
>   throwIfFail)    at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()    at
>   LDAP_TestApp.LDAPConnection.AuthenticateUser(String ldapPath, String
>   dn, String userName, String pwd, Boolean isAuthenticated)

However, it seems it is possible to have same username in different OUs
based on this link [Unique name requirement in AD](https://serverfault.com/questions/310083/unique-name-requirement-in-active-directory-ous?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) And my users are having unique DNs.

Problem is gone once i have removed one of the users in any OU.

My code is as followed:

> ```
> public string AuthenticateUser(string ldapPath, string dn, string
> userName, string pwd, bool isAuthenticated)
>     {
>             string entryPath = (dn.Trim() == string.Empty) ? ldapPath : entryPath = ldapPath + '/' + dn;
>
>             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>             AuthenticationTypes checkState;
>             DirectoryEntry searchRoot;
>             if (isAuthenticated)
>             {
>                 checkState = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
>                 searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(entryPath, userName, pwd, checkState);
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 checkState = AuthenticationTypes.None;
>                 searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(entryPath, "", "", checkState);
>             }
>
>             // Here starts the query
>             DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot)
>             {
>                 SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree,
>                 Filter = "(&" +
>                     "(objectClass=person)" +
>                     "(cn=" + userName + ")" + 
>                 ")"
>             };
>             search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("dn");
>             search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
>             search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname");
>             SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
>            //the rest is how the result being handled.
> ```

Line search.FindOne() is where the error being thrown.
I have tried:

1. Using the exact DN to authenticate
   E.g. OU=Team1,OU=DepartmentA,DC=RMS,DC=com (only one Alex)
2. Remove the filter for the searchscope.

Can anyone share some light if you have came across this before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The actions appear to be consistent as the [FindOne()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findone(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

If more than one entry is found during the search, only the first entry is returned. If no entries are found to match the search criteria, a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) is returned.

So how do you know which entry is being found? (i.e do both your "Alex's passwords match?)

You need to define a strategy to handle two user IDs with the same cn (RDN) values.

Generally this is not a good idea. When Alex(1) fails to login he may request a password reset. Even though he knows his password but his login is going against Alex(2).

Comment: Right, but i can pass in the exact entry path to where one of the Alexs that i need at since that their DN is different. And FindOne() should be able to return a result. 

Since i am developing for a client, i am trying to be aware if there is this needs and see if there is a workaround for it. Say i can allow a drop down in UI for user to choose which department he/she is at, and helps me to identify which is the exact entry path that i need.

But, i dont know why even exact path is given, but it will returned an error.